# Error occured during installation of vim

Tags: vim

After typing `sudo apt-get install vim`, I get:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11 Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running these 2 commands 1 after another

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

basically these 2 commands are deleting the lock.

Comment: Better check first if another process is using dpkg? Like having your updates installed at the sametime or synaptic open? Just deleting and starting another process could damage your dpkg database.

Comment: @fredfoo I agree with you on this but if another package is running then stopping it in middle would be the idea but that would cause more problem    than completely removing it.